# Batch to remove all subfolders that don't have subfolders of their own

Tags: loops, batch-file, recursion, directory

To be more specific about the question, I have an hierarchy of folders.

```
Render/a/b/c/d/e/f
```

where a-f are numbers between 1 and 4.

for example you could have..
Render/1/1/3/2/4/1/(Somefile.jpg)

Due to space limitations I do not need the last layer of subfolders, or their contents.

The idea I had was to write a batch file that would loop through all the folders, and their subfolders until it finds the folder that doesn't contain another subfolder, signifying that its the last folder, then deleting the folder along with its contents.

The way the system is set up, is there is a base render. That render is split up into 4 sub renders which get more detailed (hence the 1-4 sub-directories). 
As a result, each folder MAY contains 4 images, along with 4 sub directories that contain the smaller, more detailed images.
the folder isn't required to have all 4 sub-directories, it depends on the size of that particular render.
At the end, there is the most detailed set of images which isn't needed.

I can understand the 
    rd /q /s Dir1
piece of the code, along with the
    for %%i in (set)
but being able to combine them to perform this task baffles me.

1) locate all sub-directories of the render directory.
2) move to first directory, and locate all sub-directories of that.
3) repeat step 2
4) if there are no sub-directories, I know its the last render
5) delete the contents, and the directory
6) move back a directory, and continue through
7) repeat entire process with 2,3,4th directories.

I'd be able to perform this task with c#, but I'm required to have a single .bat file.

**EDIT:**
The reason why I was originally going for a batch, was because it was simple and only needed one file. However, I decided to go with a perl script because two files isn't much worse than one.

```
# read zoomlevel from generated file.js
my $zoomlevel=0;
my $maxzoom=0;
if (open OC,"Render/file.js")
{
  foreach (<OC>)
  {
    if (index($_, "zoomLevels") != -1)
    {
      @data = split(' ', $_);

      $zoomlevel=substr $data[1],0,1;
      print "$data[1]\n";
      print "$zoomlevel\n";
    }
    if (index($_, "maxZoom") != -1)
    {
      @data = split(' ', $_);

      $maxzoom=substr $data[1],0,1;
      print "$data[1]\n";
      print "$maxzoom\n";
    }
  }
  my $numdelete=$zoomlevel-$maxzoom;
  print "I'm going to delete $numdelete zoomlevels.\n";
  for($count = 0; $count < $numdelete; $count++) {
    print "deleting zoomlevel ".($zoomlevel-$count).".\n";
    my $delstr = "Render/render/".'*/' x ($zoomlevel-$count)."*.jpg";
    unlink glob "$delstr";
  }
}
else
  {print "couldn't open file\n";}
```

Then I simply created a batch file that ran the perl script.

```
@echo off
perl removal.pl
pause
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it _should_ work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with the batch language like this.  Given the following folder/file structure:

```
New folder
├───New folder (2)
│   │   New Text Document (2).txt
│   │   New Text Document.txt
│   │
│   └───New folder (3)
│       │   New Text Document (2).txt
│       │
│       └───New folder (5)
│               New Text Document (3).txt
│
└───New folder (4)
    │   New Text Document (3).txt
    │
    └───New folder (6)
        │   New Text Document (4).txt
        │
        ├───New folder (7)
        │       New Text Document.txt
        │
        └───New folder (8)
            │   New Text Document (4).txt
            │
            └───New folder (9)
                    New Text Document (5).txt
```

Folders 5, 7 and 9 should be removed.  After running the following batch file:

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

cd "New folder"

for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%i in ('dir /a:d /b /s') do (
  dir "%%i" /a:d | find /i " 2 Dir(s)" > nul
  if !errorlevel!==0 rd "%%i" /s /q
)

cd ..

endlocal
```

The folder/file structure looks like this:

```
New folder
├───New folder (2)
│   │   New Text Document (2).txt
│   │   New Text Document.txt
│   │
│   └───New folder (3)
│           New Text Document (2).txt
│
└───New folder (4)
    │   New Text Document (3).txt
    │
    └───New folder (6)
        │   New Text Document (4).txt
        │
        └───New folder (8)
                New Text Document (4).txt
```

The `for` loop enumerates all folders and passes the foldername to the `dir ... | find ...` command.  If it finds `2 Dir(s)`, meaning the `.` and `..` folders, it knows there are no other subfolders and it removes that folder.

Comment: This will fail when there are 12 or 22 or 32 directories etc.  The `"2 Dir(s)"` has to have a leading space `" 2 Dir(s)"`